# Connect to SQL Server Analysis Service from Python

Tags: python, sql-server, ssas, pyodbc

I'm using PyODBC for SQL Server 2008 database engine and it works well. I can retrieve records and execute procedures and views with no problem.

My issue is I can't connect to SQL Server 2008 Analysis Server using PyODBC. Following list shows what I've tried:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={SQL Server};Server=127.0.0.1;Database=DB1;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
```

And

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=127.0.0.1;DATABASE=DB1;Trusted_Connection=yes;UID=TB\\user;PWD=123123')
```

What's the problem? How can I address this issue?

Comment: You need to provide us with way more information than that.. error message?

Comment: What flavor of server are you on, Windows or Linux, where you are running Python? If you're on Linux, try this:

Comment: cnxn_str = 'DRIVER={FreeTDS};SERVER=yourservername.com;PORT=1433;DATABASE=db_name;UID=db_user;PWD=db_password;TDS_Version=7.2;'

Comment: cnxn = pyodbc.connect(cnx_str, autocommit=True)

Comment: Let me know if that was the issue (if you're on Linux) and I will convert it to an answer. Please also note you'll have to have FreeTDS and UnixODBC installed as well.

Comment: What is your expected output? SSAS is not an RDBMS, and doesn't support SQL queries. Are you trying to connect to the SSAS database hosted in SQL Server?

Comment: Was this ever solved?

Comment: @Spartako No, I rewrote the app using C#.