# How to connect SSAS to Python

Tags: python, pandas, ssas, olap-cube, ssas-tabular

Want to fetch data in Python Pandas DataFrame from SSAS connection, how to do?
I tried below code

```
import olap.xmla.xmla as xmla
provider = xmla.XMLAProvider()
connect = provider.connect(location='http://localhost/OLAP/msmdpump.dll',username='test',password='test')
source = connect.getOLAPSource()
```

But when importing its gives error "No module named xmla". So, I try to run "pip install xmla" but it giving error "No module name client"

Please suggest what to do and how to import SSAS data in Python pandas dataframe

Answer (score 2):

This method seemed to me the easiest.
Note: it is Possible to use if you have access to any MS SQL Server or the ability to deploy it.

1. to configure MS SQL Server:

1.1 add SQL user authorization (public roll)

1.2 allow ad hoc

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'ad hoc distributed queries', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 0
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

1.3 fix MSSQL behavior https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4582/sql-server-ad-hoc-access-to-ole-db-provider-has-been-denied-error/

Moving on to python,  the idea is to use the construct " SELECT olap.* from OpenRowset ('"+ olap_conn_string+"',' " + mdx_string +"') "+ 'as olap'

```
import pandas as pd
import pymssql 
# connect to MSSQL
try:
    connect_mssql = pymssql.connect(server=ip_mssql, user=user_mssql,password=pass_mssql, port=port_mssql)
except:
    print("exception:....")
    sys.exit()

# creating an OLAP query string via linked server MSSQL
# olap_conn_string example "MSOLAP','Provider=MSOLAP.8;Password=Pass;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=login;Data Source=SSAS Server IP or domen;Update Isolation Level=2;Initial Catalog=OLAP BD;"
# mdx_path - this is just the path to the file with the mdx request
def get_mdx_query_str(mdx_path,olap_conn_string):
    try:
        with open(mdx_path, encoding="utf8") as f:
            mdx_string = f.read()            
    except:
        print("exception:......")
        return False
    finally:
        try:
            f.close()  
        except:
            print("....") 
    mdx_query = "SELECT olap.* FROM OpenRowset('"+ olap_conn_string+"','"+ mdx_string +"')"+'as olap'
    return mdx_query

# getting the pandas dataframe
 tempdf = pd.read_sql( \
                       (get_mdx_query_str(mdx_path, olap_conn_string)) \
                        ,connect_mssql)
```

you can pass parameters to the query using the %s string formatting methods